# Pronoun order in an inverted question that contains an infinitive clause

Tags: pronoms, ordre-des-mots, infinitif, interrogative

“*Aiderez-vous ces éleves à répondre au questionnaire ?*”

If I wanted to substitute pronouns for *ces éleves* and *à répondre au questionnaire* what is the word order?

I think it might be

> aiderez-vous les y répondre

But it looks wrong!

Answer (score 8):

The right sentence would be

> *Les aiderez-vous à y répondre ?*

Note that the corresponding affirmative sentence is “*Vous les aiderez à y répondre*”. To form the corresponding interrogative, you only have to move the subject *vous* after the verb *aiderez* and tie them with a dash. *Les* is an object of *aiderez* and isn't affected by the process.

By the way, *y* only stands for *au questionnaire* so you still need the preposition *à*.

Comment: *Y* stands as usual for « *au questionnaire* », including the préposition *à*. The *à* that is left in the sentence is the one from *aider à*, not the one from *répondre à*.

Comment: Evpok, désolé mais je crois que la dernière phrase mérite plus d'explications. Je laisse mon commentaire.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je ne vois pas ce qui te manque, mais si tu as envie de rajouter un truc, je t'en prie :)